# How can i select a specific element from a string?

Tags: c#

I have the following code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string linie;
        foreach (string elem in Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Users\A\Desktop\FIles", "*.txt"))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(elem);
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(elem);
            {
                while (!reader.EndOfStream)
                {
                    linie=reader.ReadLine();
                    Console.WriteLine(linie);                         
                }
            }
            reader.Close();

        }
        Console.ReadKey();
        Console.WriteLine(DateTime.ParseExact("5/10/2005", "m/d/yyyy", null).Day);
    }
}
```

What i need is to select only the Date from a file.
For example if i have the string "the date is 20/2/2012" in a `.txt` file, i need to substract only `20/2/2012` and to compare it with the current date.

Comment: will the string alway be the same ? (Not the date but the other part)

Comment: i hope it will be. for the moment let's consider it will be always the same

Comment: you could add a `:` and split on it. (lazy solution)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want an easy lazy solution, you can always add a `:` and [Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/system.string.split.aspx) on it. (You could split on white spaces but then I would have to count for the index and I don't want to do this).

```
string   dateFromFile = "The date is : 20/2/2012";
string[] dateString =  dateFromFile.Split(':');

string myDate = dateString[1];
```

Ok I looked at my answer and decided I was too lazy...

```
string dateFromFile = "The date is 20/2/2012";
string[] dateString = dateFromFile.Split(' ');

string myDate = dateString[3];
```

It splits the string everytime it sees the sepcified character and returns a `String[]`.

In the second example (where I split on white space, the array would look like this)

```
dateString[0] = "The"
dateString[1] = "date"
dateString[2] = "is"
dateString[3] = "20/2/2012"
```

Comment: so that .Split(':') is splitting the string into 2 parts?

Comment: @user2325553: It splits the string into an array with each token between the given delimiter populating an index in the array. Here is the documenation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/b873y76a.aspx

Comment: I understand now what i have to do. Thank You

Comment: @user2325553 I updated my answer with explanations. Glad I could help